# How to vertically align an image in unknown size to the center of a div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a simple HTML button which contains text and an image:

**HTML:** *(Already on http://jsfiddle.net/EFwgN)*

```
<span class="Button">
    <img src="http://www.connectedtext.com/Image/ok.gif" />
    Small Icon
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span.Button {display:inline-block; margin:2px 4px;padding:3px 6px;
             background-color:#ddd; height:24px; line-height:24px;
             vertical-align:middle;}
span.Button img {vertical-align:middle;}
```

I can't come up with a combination that would fit these requirements:

- The image and text need to be vertically at the middle of the div, with the text in the middle of the image. It should be neat.
- *Horizontally* - the image may be in **any width**, and the button should grow to show it.
- *Vertically* - the image may be in **any height, smaller or larger** than the button. When the image is larger, I don't mind if the extra pixels are displayed or cropped, as long as it is centered.
- The button is in a fixed height. Currently I use `line-height` to center the text.
- The button should sit nicely in line with other buttons and text.
- The solution needs to work on all latest versions of major browsers, and Internet Explorer 8.

Here's a jsfiddle with my current code: **http://jsfiddle.net/EFwgN**
(note the small icon is slightly below the center of the button)

Comment: I know there are countless duplicates, but I could get anything to work well...

Comment: Ok, it's on. *(at least)* **150** reputation in bounty currency for a good solution, extra **50** if the solution supports IE8 in compatibility mode.

Comment: I've found a way to disable compatibility view - so no bonus points!  http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/03/css-ie8-meta-tag-to-disable.html

Comment: Here's another failed attempt, with `display:table-cell` - http://jsfiddle.net/uRKUn/

Comment: Does this have to be a fully css/html solution? Or could it use js?

Comment: @Py - Without boasting too much, I think I can get a working JavaScript solution in a few minutes `:)` . I'm looking for a CSS solution, if possible. I've seen much more impressive things done with CSS... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I assumed that but I just wanted to be sure `:)`

Comment: If the image is bigger than the container (like the big checkmark in the middle button on the fiddle), I'd have to say it's not possible without javascript. At least not to my knowledge.

Comment: Do the images have to be in HTML? I'd use these icons as background images on your spans, and have a class for each icon.

Comment: @Artyom - With `background-image` I need a class for each image, which also include the width of icon. Adding so much information is no fun. Besides, some of my icons *may* have alternate text (I write a generic control).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution, if you need no less than IE8 (in Standards mode): http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/EFwgN/31/

Just add `margin: -100px 0` to `img`, so the negative margin would eat any large height:

```
span.Button img {vertical-align:middle; margin:-100px 0;
                 position:relative; top:-2px;}
```

I've added `position: relative; top:-2px;` just to look it better :)

But if you'll need support for compatibility mode or IE lt 8 (for some reason), the thing with margin won't work. So you'll need an extra markup: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/EFwgN/28/, but it's somewhat hacky and works only with the fixed button's height (like in your example).

Comment: IE8 Compatibility mode is dead to me. forget it `:)`. Also, the image isn't *exactly* centered, It looks better with `-1px`, for me, which worries me. Interesting though!

Comment: It's centered according to the font's ascenders and descenders, but not visually, so yeah, `-1px` or `-2px` would fix the visual part :)

Comment: So if you'd use another inline-block instead of just text, you'll see that it's perfectly centered: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/EFwgN/36/ The problem is in text's vertical alignment, so it's fine to fix it by moving image a little bit.

Comment: The last one is pretty good! Needs one extra pixel though: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/EFwgN/38/ Never saw this use of negative margins. I'll see how that's working for me (I'll test all browsers, etc). Looks good so far. Thanks!

Comment: The top and bottom negative margin is a good trick. It works well here, and seems good is all browsers I've tested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use table-based display.  Requires shrinking of image due to conflict between `display:table-cell;` and `height:24px`.  Very similar to your aborted attempt from the comments, but includes the required `display:block;` on the image: http://jsfiddle.net/shanethehat/5ck3s/

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a good option if I want to rescale the images, but here I prefer not to.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, using jQuery:

```
$(".button img").load(function()
          {
              $(this).each(function()
                           {
                               sh = $(this).outerHeight();
                               if (sh > 24){
                               alert(sh);
                              $(this).css("margin-top", - (sh - 24) / 2 + 'px');
                              }
                           });
          });
```

Edit: Just saw that you wanted it pure CSS, well, here's to the code gulfers out there! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the image shrink in the case where it is indeed taller than the button?

```
span.Button img {
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I rather not - I have some images that are padded with transparent pixels, and I can freely hide them. It isn't bad, by the way, but the images are still not at the center of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I probably missed some of the requirements, as setting span.Button's height to auto did the trick for me.

If what you wanted is button growing only horizontally, with vertical overflow cropped, than maybe I'd do it like this:

```
span.Button {display:inline-block; margin:2px 4px;padding:3px 6px;
             background-color:#ddd; width:auto; height:24px; line-height:24px;overflow:hidden;
             vertical-align:middle;
             }
```

using a bit of javascript to determine img height, and then center it accordingly.

Comment: The large icon is cropped, with is OK, but the text and icon aren't centered: http://jsfiddle.net/uNDCL/

Answer (score 0):

How about... this?

http://jsfiddle.net/92K8J/

Added `display:inline-block` to the images, and removed the fixed `height`of the container.

Comment: Sorry, but the fixed height is one of the most important requirements... I have some images padded with transparent pixels, mostly, and I don't want to crop them because 1. It's boring 2. They are shared with other ui elements, and I don't want to copy them.