# How do I vertically center an img in a div?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have an `<img>` that I want to center in a `<div>`. All previous answers I've found here use some hack or require you to know the image's width, which varies in my case.

Horizontal centering with `text-align: center` on the parent is easy. I can't figure out how to vertically align.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfMYy/)**

FYI Facebook does this well using just HTML and CSS. So please no `<table>` or javascript hacks. It looks like they are using something with `line-height` to make their `<img>` vertically center.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [How to vertically align an image in unknown size to the center of a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7228762/7586)

Comment: have you tried using position:absolute ?

Comment: @imulsion I can't think of a way to position the photos using `absolute`. I've seen a lot of mention about using 50% or other percentages, but that doesn't work if your image varies in size.

Comment: I've seen that @Kobi but it seems so hacky for such a common situation. Really hoping someone knows how it's done.

Comment: Actually, the only thing you are missing is `line-height:400px;`: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/ZfMYy/5/ (the question I linked has an additional requirement of image that it larger than its container)

Comment: You're the man Kobi :) Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Kobi feel free to post that answer

Comment: Ok, I'll post that `:)`. By the way - were you the one who vigorously down-voted all answers? These good people are just trying to help.

Comment: Only the one that stated `vertical-align: middle` when it was already in my code :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `vertical-align: middle;` is not to useful on its own, you also need to set the line-height: `line-height:400px;`.

This is useful if you have no other text in your `<div>` (except maybe a single line).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/ZfMYy/5/

Answer (score -1):

Add a rule in your css class:

```
 {vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
html, body, #wrapper {
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
#wrapper td {
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}


<html>
<body>
   <table id="wrapper">
      <tr>
         <td><img src="logo.png" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables are bad style @kobi showed how this can simply be done using proper semantic HTML and just using `vertical-align: middle` on your img.

Comment: i know its a bad style, but tables are gr8 sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

As @kobi mentioned in a comment, all you need to do is set a `line-height` on your containing `div`. No tables.

[jsFiddle example of vertically centered image](http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/ZfMYy/5/)