# vertically centered image in div

Tags: html, css, background-image, vertical-alignment

I try to vertically center an image in the middle of the body but nothing seems to work. I've tried different tricks found here (height 100%, table-cell, position:relative...), but with no luck until now. My code is
html:

```
 <div id="container">
   <div id="header">Header</div>
   <div id="body">
       <div class="image"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">Footer</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ccc;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;
}
.image {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/") no-repeat center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background:#ccc;
}
```

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dragoeco/hjcz6j0r/1/
I looking for a working solution with IE8+ so maybe there is a jQuery way to do that job? What is important for me is to keep the footer at the bottom of the viewport so that's why I used a obsolute position for footer. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically align an image in unknown size to the center of a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228762/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-in-unknown-size-to-the-center-of-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
.image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

It works everywhere (except IE6-7, position relative may be needed there). You can do the same for horizontal centering.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hjcz6j0r/7/

Comment: All of what was proposed here until now worked fine but this is an elegant and easy way. Thanks Sergey

Comment: You are very welcome. In my opinion simplest solution is the best. For cross browser compatibility, negative margins are supported in all browsers (only sometimes not working in IE6 and 7, position relative fixes it there).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe :

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kj76C/18/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-top:-60px; //height of the footer
}
#body {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.image {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/") no-repeat center;
    height:200px;
}

#header {
   background:#ccc;
   padding:10px;
}

#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. But I hesitate between the Sergey solution and yours. Which one do you think is better: table-cell or absolute position? I mean, is there a difference for the cross browser compatibility?

Comment: @dragoeco I don't use absolute position, my solution come for CSS Tricks. http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ . So i think my solution is better, but i don't want to be arrogant

Answer (score 1):

I had success with the following CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ccc;
   padding:10px;
   position: relative;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/") no-repeat center ;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background:#ccc;
}
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical